# FAILED: ParseException line 1:36 cannot recognize input near '1987'

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to creat an external table in Hive with this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 1987(
    YEAR INT,
    MONTH INT,
    DAYOFMONTH INT,
    DAYOFWEEK INT,
    DEPTIME INT,
    CRS INT,
    ARRTIME TIME,
    CARRIER STRING,
    FLIGHTNUM INT,
    TAILNUM STRING,
    ACTUALELAPSED INT,
    CRSELAPSED INT,
    AIRTIME INT,
    ARRDELAY INT,
    DEPDELAY INT,
    ORIGIN STRING,
    DEST STRING,
    DISTANCE INT,
    TAXIIN INT,
    TAXIOUT INT,
    CANCELLED INT,
    CANCELLATIONCODE STRING,
    DIVERTED INT,
    CARRIERDELAY INT,
    WEATHERDELAY INT,
    NASDELAY INT,
    SECURITYDELAY INT,
    LATEAIRCRAFT INT,
    Origin CHAR(1))
COMMENT 'A??O 1987'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
location '/user/raj_ops/PROYECTO/'1987.csv';
```

But get the following error:

> org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling
>   statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:36 cannot recognize input
>   near '1987' '(' 'YEAR' in table name

Anyone knows why?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

location should be `'/user/raj_ops/PROYECTO/'` (without file itself). If you have other files in the same location then move them to separate locations, like `/user/raj_ops/PROYECTO/1987/` for 1987. Because table can be built on top of location, not file.

And table name cannot start with digits. use backquotes `1987` or rename it like `year_1987`

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to escape the table name with back-ticks if its numeric:

```
`1987`
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra quote in the location value.Remove that.

```
location '/user/raj_ops/PROYECTO/'1987.csv';
```

Should be

```
location '/user/raj_ops/PROYECTO/1987.csv';
```